# Convert normal image into infrared or ultraviolet?

Tags: jpeg

I have seen searching for infrared and ultraviolet images of plants eg: grape plants. but i can not find a reasonable images from the search. And also I have tried to buy the camera to take the picture myself but you know those cameras are so expensive that I cannot afford.

I am doing my thesis under image processing using different imaging techniques. if you all could help me to find images of infrared and ultraviolet images or you could let me know if i can buy those pictures please?

Or you if could please tell me that is it possible to convert the normal picture to infrared picutre or ultraviolet picture ?

Thanks.!

Comment: You mean fake-infrared and fake-ultraviolet, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to convert an ordinary photo into a physically correct infrared or ultraviolet photo, just as it's not possible to convert a picture taken with a red filter to a photo taken by a green filter. They use different frequencies of light. There are some details lost if the specific prequencies are not captured.

For example: flowers have very rich colouring in the ultraviolet range, but they are mostly monochromatic in the optical frequencies. This is very hard to fake. Also, the human body emits radiation in the infrared range, meaning it's perfectly visible even without any light sources (if you have the correct equipment). A human body does not emit in the visible range.

If that were possible, all the expensive real-infrared and real-ultraviolet cameras would use this process, thus being much cheaper. All the expensive X-Ray machines in the hospitals would be completely useless - just take a picture with an ordinary cell phone and process.

However, you *can* fake the effect. It's no good for scientific measurements but it is usable for artistic reasons. Open the picture in any decent image editor, and play with the colors. Play with channel mixing (you have at least 12 sliders to play with). Play with selections. You can apply different color effects to different regions of the image. Play with magic lasso to select specific objects or feather the selection to create a gradual change. Gimp has a nice feature where you can paint into the selection mask rather than to the image itself - so you can select a region or tweak a selection with paint brush too. Play with layers. You can have two layers with different color effects and blur between them by painting the top layer alpha channel. Play with the built-in filters. Play with different layer mixing modes. Play with color balance curves. Do what you need to get the artistic effect you want. You can mix different photos of different aspects of the same object, or photos of the same object with different lighting conditions (natural sunlight, artificial lighting, taken through a pair of sunglasses ...) to get more color channels to mix...

You can get a rough estimate of what's *really* happening in the *near* ultraviolet region as long as the camera is at least *a little* sensitive in that region. You you can't find an UV-pass filter, take a photo with an UV-blocking filter and without the filter, balance and subtract. do not expect much, though. Still, it could give you some hints how to achieve a semi-realistic color effect.

Comment: I know they are completely in different region of electromagnetic spectrum. But Ultraviolet fluorescence is in the visible spectrum So I was so curious that if it is possible then i can convert it to use it in my thesis. Thanks @Jan Dvorak

Comment: i was curious on this topic as how things see in non visible sprectrum, as as of today we see black hole as one application of this, so are there any tools with which we can implement the coverting a visible spectrum image to non visibale spectrum image